# Dwarf sunflower closing

Tags: diagnosis, sunflowers

Can anyone tell me why my sunflower is closed up? It didnt look like this a few days ago, it was completely open, it has a smaller flower on its side so i thought it had to do with that but im at a loss of what i can do any suggestions? Should I cut off the smaller flower? There are also multiple smaller buds growing on this sunflower my other one doesnt have any.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typical case of mutation. Generally, hybrid plants have genes which do often mutate into deformed looking parts, it's a rare occurrence but means no harm for your plants.

This exact mutation is known as fasciation, it does seems to limit on genetic mutation as a cause, but can also be caused by hormonal imbalance. So you can look up for it. But to me, it looks beautiful.

[Fasciation- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasciation)